# In layered navigation can I modify the collection before the filters are applied?

Tags: event-observer, enterprise-1.14

*The duplicate post does not touch on the same topic as I am. Though I did try the solution and was able to modify the collection I ended up with the same results as explained below.*

Using the configuration below, I am able to modify my collection, *but it only applies to the results on the current pagination page*. So, if I am on page one and I have a product starting with the letter A and modify the collection with `->addAttributeToFilter("name",["like"=>"a%"])` I see only the products that start with the letter a **for the current page**. If I am on page one and modify the collection with `->addAttributeToFilter("name",["like"=>"m%"])` I do not see products beginning with the letter M, I get Magento's "no products found" message. If I go to the pagination page that contains products with the letter M and use `->addAttributeToFilter("name",["like"=>"m%"])` I see only products starting with M that were on the current page.

How do I filter by letter *prior to pagination and any other filters* being applied?

config.xml

```
        <catalog_product_collection_apply_limitations_after>
            <observers>
                <etre_alphapagination>
                    <type>model</type>
                    <class>etre_alphapagination/observer</class>
                    <method>applyFilter</method>
                </etre_alphapagination>
            </observers>
        </catalog_product_collection_apply_limitations_after>
```

Observer.php

```
public function applyFilter($observer)
{

    if ($alphaFilter = Mage::getModel('etre_alphapagination/parametersactions')->currentAlphaFilter()) {
        $event = $observer->getEvent();
        $collection = Mage::getModel('etre_alphapagination/parametersactions')->applyFilter($event->getCollection(), $alphaFilter, "name");
        return $this;
    }
}
```

`Mage::getModel('etre_alphapagination/parametersactions')->applyFilter($event->getCollection(), $alphaFilter, "name")` refers to:

```
public function applyFilter($collection, $query = "", $attribute = 'name') //let's provide the option to filter the collection by whichever attribute desired
{
    try {
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('name', array('like' => $query . '%'));
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        Mage::logException($e);
    }
    return $collection;
}
```

## Update

So, this is fully functional ([Module GIT](https://github.com/tylerofathenry/Etre_Alphapagination)) on a fresh install on Magento CE 1.9. I've disabled all non-core modules on my Magento instance and am still seeing the same results as described above.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this question correctly. SQL doesn't care WHEN you add any filter to the collection. If you filter by first letter BEFORE the collection is loaded it works and shows only products which start with 'm' (or whatever letter)

Comment: Fabian - I have added clarification through my question. Thank you for helping out.